# VB.NET draw image (set pixel)

Tags: vb.net, winforms, pixel

lets say that i want to create image with width and height 64 and set all pixels to black

```
dim b as bitmap

b.width = 64
b.height = 64

for y = 0 to 64
    for x = 0 to 64
        b.setpixel(x,y ,color.black)
    next
next

dim p as new panel

p.width = b.width
p.hieght = b.height
p.backgroundimage(b)
```

the code not working

Comment: How can it possibly be working? It does not even compile.

Comment: Your width and height are 64 but your loops have 65 iterations

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dim b As Bitmap = New Bitmap(64, 64)

    For y = 0 To 64

        For x = 0 To 64

            b.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Black)

        Next

    Next

    b.Save("bitmap1.bmp")
```

Comment: Dim p As New Panel p.BackImageUrl = "bitmap1.bmp" is how it's used

Comment: or if panel is already declared you don't need the dim p as new panel part.. and replace p with the name of your panel.

Comment: I think the correct is "For y = 0 To 63" and "For x = 0 To 63" or it'll throw an exception

Comment: Shoot, you could be right about that.. I didn't put this in a test environment to make sure.